# EF Core - Can't login to sql server

Tags: entity-framework-core

Been working with a .Net Core app and have been successfully connecting to sql server 2008 sp3 in our qa environment for a while, just tried deploying it to our production environment and am getting this error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Unable to write data to the transport connection: Unknown error 10054.)`

This is specifically happening in a .Net Core app running in a docker container. Does anyone know what could be the issue? I have seen threads encouraging upgrading sql server to service pack 3, we have done that. Also made sure the TLS settings on the server were correct.

Comment: Hello scotty, has your problem been solved? I'm with the same error but I haven't upgraded sqlserver yet.

Comment: There were two separate errors I experienced. First you must upgrade to service pack 3 or it won't work. Second, our production db was running on a different port than the default and there was a very specific connection string format I had to use - though unfortunately I don't remember exactly what that was.